# MYSQL Insert for each Item

Tags: mysql, sql

Maybe my question is stupid but... is there a way in mysql (without php or others)
to insert data into  one table for each object in another table?

For example:

```
Table: Items
Item 1    ItemClass 1
Item 2    ItemClass 2
Item 3    ItemClass 1


Table: File_Class
File 1 ItemClass 1
File 2 ItemClass 1
File 3 ItemClass 2
File 4 ItemClass 1
File 5 ItemClass 2
```

Can i use only MYSQL to insert a Item/file Combination for each Item into the File_Status table like this: ?
Simething like

In best case including a check if the combination is unique and does not exsist already.

```
For Each Item in Table Items 
- For Each File From File_Class Where ItemClass = ItemClass(in Items)
- Intert Into File Status itemID, FileID, status = open




Table: File_status
ID    itemID   File     Status
1     Item 1   File 1   open
2     Item 1   File 2   open
3     Item 1   File 4   open
```

I know how to do it with php/mysql but maybe there is a way to do it only with one query.

Thanks for any Idea

Comment: Why are you only getting 3 rows instead of 15?

Comment: it was only an example... i know i will get x rows for ech item. :)

Comment: and how you come to an expectet number of 15 rows?
Item 1 has 3 Files
Item 2 has 2
and
Item 3 has 3.

Makes 8 in total for me or am i wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic suggests:

```
insert into file_status (itemId, file, status)
    select i.itemId, fc.file, 'open'
    from items i cross join
         file_class fc;
```

However, this inserts 15 rows.  If you want to "align" the tables, then you need some way to join them.  `row_number()` provides this information:

```
insert into file_status (itemId, file, status)
    select i.itemId, fc.file, 'open'
    from (select i.*, row_number() over (order by itemId) as seqnum
          from items i
         ) i join
         (select fc.*, row_number() over (order by file) as seqnum
          from file_class fc
         ) fc
         on i.seqnum = fc.seqnum;
```

Comment: Im a mysql beginner... so i will need a moment trying to understand your code :)

Comment: i think i start to understand. I will try this with my tables.

Thx for the fast answer :)

Comment: it worked and i think i got it. But i forgot a middle table so there is mor work to do^^